# Get the path to an execuatble in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, path, taskmanager

I'm making a task manager type program and I need to get the path to every file. I don't want to find out the directory off my own executable. Just external files.

This is the beginning of getting the executable:

```
For Each OneProcess As Process In Process.GetProcesses
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Please indent code by four spaces instead of making it bold. Also, it would be useful to know what language you are coding in. Please add that to your question by editing, and also add an appropriate tag.

Comment: @Anders Thanks for the comment. I changed the title. Hope it's better now. Sometimes I can get the code in the "code" box, but sometimes I can't get it to work. But thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

To find the directory and file name of any Process use `MainModule.FileFileName`
Here is sample code to help

```
System.Diagnostics.Process mm22= System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")[0];
string stp = mm22.MainModule.FileName; //location of the executable with filename
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I'm just now coming back to this page. Still new here and didn't know that all my questions were in my "profile" page?

Comment: An exception was thrown on the second line. I'm doing vb.net and don't really know C# too much. I ran the code through a C# to VB converter and this is what it came up with... it's the dim stp part that throws the exception  Did the code convert ok?                                                                                                                                  Dim mm22 As System.Diagnostics.Process = Process.GetProcessesByName(OneProcess.ProcessName)(0)
            Dim stp As String = mm22.MainModule.FileName

Comment: Here's the error:                                                                                                            System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was unhandled
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=Access is denied
  NativeErrorCode=5

Comment: One more comment until I hear from you, (I promise). If I could get that code to work, I would have no problem extracting the icons from each file!

Comment: You need to run your program with higher privileges and try.

Comment: Not quite sure I know what you mean. I ran the exe as admin and got the same result. Is there a way you can do it in code?

Comment: Can you tell me which process is giving that error!!

Comment: you might be trying to access 64bit process from 32 bit that can throw this exception.

Comment: Well... then I think I know what might be happening... going to check something out then I'll get back to you. I just got a stackoverflow msg that says were talking to much. but I don't have enough points to do chat. I'll get back to you in just a bit

Comment: Do me a favor, send me a message to: jumper_at_riseup.net. then I'll delete this post.

Comment: I'm just going to leave that last msg up. I'm going to do some extreme things and I won't be on here again until much later tonight. Have to reinstall vs2015 talk later

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.. browse for answers, got close but it wasnt what i was excepting, then i saw GetProcessesByName which reminded me of javascript..so i changed it to GetProcessById.

```
For Each p In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()
  ListBox1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName & " - " & p.Id.ToString() & " - ")
Next
 Dim id = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString.Split("-")(1).Trim
 Dim p As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(id)
MsgBox( p.MainModule.FileName)
```